# Angular check if value is in an array in angular template

Tags: angular

i wanted to check if a value exists in an array and return true if it does and false if it dosent in an angular checkbox input field.

here is the code

```
 <div style="margin-left: 20px;" *ngFor="let li of permissions;">
            <nz-form-item *ngIf="li.entity === 'Staffs'">
              <nz-form-control style="margin-bottom: -25px;">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{li.id}}" [checked]="li.id == select" name="staff">{{select}} - {{li.id}}
              </nz-form-control> 
            </nz-form-item>
            
          </div>
```

select is an array containg id of the selected checkbox values any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to perform the check. But it's not a good idea to bind a function to a property like `[checked]=select.includes(li.id)`. In case of default change detection strategy it will get executed for each CD cycle might have a performance impact.

Instead you could run the check in the controller and introduce a new boolean property in the object.e

**Controller**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // initialize `permissions` and `select` arrays

  this.permissions = this.permissions.map(permission => ({
    ...permission,
    isChecked: this.select.includes(permission.id)
  });
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div style="margin-left: 20px;" *ngFor="let li of permissions;">
  <nz-form-item *ngIf="li.entity === 'Staffs'">
    <nz-form-control style="margin-bottom: -25px;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{li.id}}" [checked]="li.isChecked" name="staff">{{select}} - {{li.id}}
    </nz-form-control> 
  </nz-form-item>          
</div>
```

Comment: i tried it but it is not working i am a beginner on angular so bear with me :)

Comment: The code in the controller is only an example. For actual implementation, you'd have to show how the variables `permissions` and `select` are initialized.

Comment: It is working now but how can i attach the selected values and the other empty check box values if they got selected to the NgModel?

Answer (score 1):

Does your `select` array contain only ids? If so, you can follow @michael's approach or just an add-on approach:

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="{{li.id}}" [checked]="select.indexOf(li.id) > -1" name="staff">
```

Your checkbox will be checked if `select` array contains id.

Comment: It is working now but how can i attach the selected values and the other empty check box values if they got selected to the NgModel?